# Expo does not create Websocket ApolloClient instance when started with expo start

Tags: react-native, expo, apollo, react-apollo

I use the [react-apollo](https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo/blob/master/src/index.js) boilerplate in my `expo` project.

So far the project runs fine. But when I have interactions with my database it fails with:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network error: Response not successful:
> Received status code 400

and

> The development server has disconnected.

and

[image: XHR error]

So what is the best way to continue? This is the `ApolloClient` that needs to be running for the connection with my database:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

Before I switched to `expo` I simply run `react-scripts start` and the database and code were up and running. But now with `expo` it only starts the code.

Is there something special to `expo` to also have the database up and running?

There is also no difference between `Android` and `web`:
[image]

Or do I need to outsource that Client and run it there in a new instance? But this has side effects like I cannot access things like `state` anymore. So this is not really sensefull right?

Found those integrations into the App function but they did not work for me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56298339/1077633
- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/integrations/react-native/
- https://dzone.com/articles/integrate-a-react-native-app-with-graphql-and-apol
- https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-with-apollo-part-2-apollo-client-8b4ad4915cf5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it helped to restart the GraphQL server once again via `yarn start`.

It not, try to rebuild all modules after cleaning.